# ORDER BY primary key is super slow, even though the subquery is very fast

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, primary-key

```
create table account_match
(
    id                 int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    smaller_account_id int(11) unsigned                    not null,
    bigger_account_id  int(11) unsigned                    not null,
    match_origin       varchar(50)                         null,
    created            timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    constraint account_match_account_id_fk
        foreign key (smaller_account_id) references account (id)
            on delete cascade,
    constraint account_match_account_id_fk_2
        foreign key (bigger_account_id) references account (id)
            on delete cascade

create index account_match_smaller_account_id_bigger_account_id_index
    on account_match (smaller_account_id, bigger_account_id);
);
```

```
create table private_message
(
    id                  int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    sender_account_id   int(11) unsigned                     not null,
    receiver_account_id int(11) unsigned                     null,
    message             text                                 null,
    viewed              tinyint(1) default 0                 not null,
    created             timestamp  default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    constraint private_message_account_id_fk
        foreign key (sender_account_id) references account (id)
            on delete cascade,
    constraint private_message_account_id_fk_2
        foreign key (receiver_account_id) references account (id)
            on delete cascade
);

create index private_message_receiver_account_id_sender_account_id_index
    on private_message (receiver_account_id, sender_account_id);

create index private_message_sender_account_id_receiver_account_id_index
    on private_message (sender_account_id, receiver_account_id);
```

```
SELECT account_match.*
FROM (
         SELECT account_match.id
         FROM account_match
         WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                      FROM account_match
                      WHERE smaller_account_id = 1
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT id
                      FROM account_match
                      WHERE bigger_account_id = 1)
           AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT TRUE
                          FROM private_message
                          WHERE sender_account_id = smaller_account_id
                            AND receiver_account_id = bigger_account_id)
           AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT TRUE
                          FROM private_message
                          WHERE sender_account_id = bigger_account_id
                            AND receiver_account_id = smaller_account_id)
     ) match_ids
         JOIN account_match using (id)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

```
1   PRIMARY account_match       index   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       20  100 Backward index scan
1   PRIMARY account_match       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   miliar.account_match.id 1   100 Using where
6   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  private_message     ref private_message_receiver_account_id_sender_account_id_index,private_message_sender_account_id_receiver_account_id_index private_message_sender_account_id_receiver_account_id_index 9   miliar.account_match.bigger_account_id,miliar.account_match.smaller_account_id  1   100 Using index
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  private_message     ref private_message_receiver_account_id_sender_account_id_index,private_message_sender_account_id_receiver_account_id_index private_message_sender_account_id_receiver_account_id_index 9   miliar.account_match.smaller_account_id,miliar.account_match.bigger_account_id  1   100 Using index
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  account_match       eq_ref  PRIMARY,account_match_smaller_account_id_bigger_account_id_index    PRIMARY 4   func    1   26.57   Using where
4   DEPENDENT UNION account_match       eq_ref  PRIMARY,account_match_smaller_account_id_bigger_account_id_index,account_match_account_id_fk_2  PRIMARY 4   func    1   5   Using where
```

The point of the query is to get matches for account with the ID of 1 (will be other IDs other times of course), where neither user messaged each other. The main query (subquery) finishes in less than 20ms, but once I add the ORDER BY id DESC it goes up to 20sec. There's about 710k rows that are returned from the subquery, but the size shouldn't matter since I'm trying to order by the primary key right? Any way to fix this speed?

Comment: I am sure there is a better and more efficient way to write this query.  However, you need to ask a question that has sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the entire query.  Your "point" of the query doesn't explain much of what is going on.  For instance, why bother with the `join`.  Why not just select all the columns you want in the subquery?

Comment: Maybe there is a more efficient way, but for what it achieves it's plenty efficient for me. Because doing this tends to speed up my other queries, where i put a limit/order by within the subquery and then do a join on it. It's not the case here, and no matter where I put the order by, it's still slow. That's why I made this post, this always works flawlessly, until this query.

Comment: What is the purpose of , JOIN account_match using (id)

Comment: Part of a [mre] is all DDL. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: MySQL 8. The result is that I want to know why the sort by id is not fast, and how to fix it, since doing SELECT * FROM account_match ORDER BY id DESC takes less than 10ms. So why not this code?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Relevant research before posting re SQL performance includes basics of optimization/performance in general & your DBMS--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following and see (as I find most of your code seems obsolete)

**The following didn't work**

```
SELECT *
FROM account_match
WHERE (smaller_account_id = 1 or bigger_account_id = 1)
    AND EXISTS(SELECT TRUE
                   FROM private_message
                   WHERE (sender_account_id != bigger_account_id or receiver_account_id != smaller_account_id)
                    AND  (sender_account_id != smaller_account_id or receiver_account_id != bigger_account_id))
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 20
```

Try this

```
-- Create a Temp table and get data from the faster query into that.
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a_m_temp
SELECT account_match.id
FROM account_match
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
        FROM account_match
        WHERE smaller_account_id = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id
        FROM account_match
        WHERE bigger_account_id = 1)
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT TRUE
            FROM private_message
            WHERE sender_account_id = smaller_account_id
            AND receiver_account_id = bigger_account_id)
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT TRUE
            FROM private_message
            WHERE sender_account_id = bigger_account_id
            AND receiver_account_id = smaller_account_id)

-- Inner Join the temp. table to the main

Select a.* from
account_match a
INNER JOIN a_m_temp t
ON a.id = t.id
Order by a.id
Limit 20
```

Comment: Wrong results, and 1.7 sec to complete. To get correct results i need to do (smaller_account_id = 1 or bigger_account_id = 1), and that takes 20 seconds.

Comment: @Damian , Please check now, also let me know how long it takes if you run your query.

Comment: it went over 40 seconds and I turned it off. It did a full table scan on the account_match table, which has > 5mil rows

Comment: OK @Damian I provided my last attempt :(

Answer (score 0):

"shouldn't matter since I'm trying to order by the primary key right" -- No.  The Optimizer is likely to work on the `WHERE` clause, which is complex, then sort the results based on the `ORDER BY`.  Only if the filtering can be fully done with an `INDEX` will it consider whether it can also do the sorting and `LIMIT`, too.

Furthermore, the subquery is hiding an `IN` clause, which is logically unordered.  And that is hiding in a "derived" table (the subquery in the `FROM` clause).

In later versions of MySQL, the Optimizer will consider creating a index for a derived table.  I don't see that in your `EXPLAIN`; it would be indicated by `<auto-key>`.

Meanwhile, I am lost as to why you have the extra table and smaller/bigger.

I think that optimizing will involve getting rid of the `IN ( SELECT ... )`, perhaps thus:

```
     FROM account_match
     WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                  FROM account_match
                  WHERE smaller_account_id = 1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT id
                  FROM account_match
                  WHERE bigger_account_id = 1)
     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( ... )
       AND NOT EXISTS ( ... )
```

-->

```
     FROM ( SELECT  id
                  FROM account_match
                  WHERE smaller_account_id = 1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT id
                  FROM account_match
                  WHERE bigger_account_id = 1 ) AS x
     JOIN account_match USING(id)
     WHERE NOT EXISTS ( ... )
       AND NOT EXISTS ( ... )
```

Also, `account_match` needs an index *starting with* `bigger_account_id` since the two half of the `UNION` need different indexes (in this case).

Please, when using multiple tables, qualify (preferably with a short alias) all column names.  For example, I need to figure out what table(s) these are in: `WHERE sender_account_id = smaller_account_id`.

Comment: Where do I add the "and NOT EXISTS..." code? I tried in the subquery (takes 3sec)/outside of it (takes 7sec). There is an index on bigger_account_id since it's a FK. sender/receiver are in the private_message table, smaller/bigger in account_match

Comment: yeah that's what i meant outside the subquery. It takes 7 sec